# TTF_RenderText_Solid memory leak, despite running SDL_FreeSurface

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am writing a function to render a menu screen to my sdl_window, but I am getting a huge memory leak in the function where i render text to the surface. I run TTF_RenderText_Solid, blit the new surface to the main one and free the textsurface with SDL_FreeSurface as the code below shows.

```
void show_button(SDL_Surface *surface, button_t *button) {
  SDL_Surface *tmp = NULL;
  tmp = TTF_RenderText_Solid(button->font, button->name,button->color);
  SDL_BlitSurface(tmp, NULL, surface, &button->box);
  SDL_FreeSurface(tmp);
  return;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated since I don't understand why the SDL_FreeSurface call doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak? How much memory is being leaked? I have numerous applications that use nearly the exact same code, I think it leaks a bit, but not much. My suggestion: save the rendered surface in a variable, only free it when you stop showing the button. I expect each call to RenderText may be leaking a bit.

Comment: My program calls this function whenever i move my mouse cursorwithin the window. And if i look at the task manager while moving my mouse cursor I can see the memory usage increasing by 10MB or so a second. But when I stop moving the cursor it stops increasing.

Comment: Like I said, I think that there might be a leak in the TTF_RenderText_Solid implementation. Either way you shouldn't re-render the text unless it changes. Doing so is an enormous waste of resources. Just re-use the old surface and only create a new one when you have to.